# UML class diagram with inheritance depending on properties values

Tags: inheritance, uml, class-diagram

The example is the following :

```
 -----------                -------------------- 
|     X     | 1..1    0..1 |    <<abstract>>    |
|           |<>------------|         Y          |
|-----------|              |--------------------|
| +a:bool   |              | +b:positiveInteger |
'-----------'              '--------------------'
```

In the real world, abstract Y can be a concrete A, B or C, according to the following rules :

- when `a` is `true`, Y is an A class ;
- when `a` is `false` and `b == 1`, Y is a B class ;
- when `a` is `false` and `b > 1`, Y is a C class.

How would you modelize these rules of inheritance in an UML class diagram ?

Comment: I wouldn't. Those are side constraints and don't belong in the class diagram itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [OCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Constraint_Language) langauge for this.

First you should extend your diagram and introduce the three concrete subclasses, `A`, `B`, and `C` of `Y`, then you need an OCL constraint like this:

```
context X:
inv: (self.a implies self.y isOclTypeOf(A)) and
     (((not self.a) and (not self.y.isOclUndefined())) implies (self.y.b = 1 implies self.y.isOclTypeOf(B))) and
     (((not self.a) and (not self.y.isOclUndefined())) implies (self.y.b > 1 implies self.y.isOclTypeOf(C)))
```

Comment: [Schematron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron) seems to work as well, for XML documents.